# Linear algebra question: How can I get this cost function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I reading a book about control theory. But that's not why I'm here. I want to minimize this cost function:

$$J = (R_s - Y)^T(R_s - Y) + U^T\bar R U$$

Where: 
$$Y = Fx_0 + \Phi U$$

And

$$F = \begin{bmatrix}
CA\\ 
CA^2\\ 
CA^3\\ 
\vdots \\ 
CA^{N_p}
\end{bmatrix} , \Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
CB &0  &0  &\cdots   & 0\\ 
CAB & CB & 0  & \cdots & 0\\ 
CA^2B& CAB & 0 &\cdots  &0 \\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 
CA^{N_p-1}B & CA^{N_p-2}B & CA^{N_p-3}B & \cdots  & CA^{N_p-N_c}B 
\end{bmatrix}$$

also $x_0$ is a vector. The rest are matrices.

**Question:**

According to my book, the author got this equation:

$$J = (R_s −Fx_0)^T (R_s −Fx_0)-2U^T \Phi^T (R_s -Fx_0)+U^T (\Phi^T \Phi+ \bar R)U$$

From:

$$J = (R_s - Y)^T(R_s - Y) + U^T\bar R U$$
$$Y = Fx_0 + \Phi U$$

How is that possible? I may feel dumb right now, but I haven't solve it.

Shouln't it be instead:

$$J = (R_s - Fx_0 - \Phi U)^T(R_s - Fx_0 - \Phi U) + U^T\bar R U$$

Litterature:

"Model Predictive Control System Design and Implementation Using MATLAB®.pdf", page 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new matrix variable 
$$\eqalign{
 M &= (R_s-Fx_0) \cr
}$$
and note that
$$ (M-\Phi U) = (R_s-Y) $$ 
Expand the cost function in terms of this new variable
$$\eqalign{
 J &= (M-\Phi U)^T(M-\Phi U) + U^TRU \cr
 &= (M^TM - 2U^T\Phi^TM + U^T\Phi^T\Phi U) + U^TRU \cr
 &= M^TM - 2U^T\Phi^TM + U^T(\Phi^T\Phi+R)U \cr
}$$
Now substitute the definition of $M$ into that last line to recover the author's equation.